# Where are ros2 message ostream operators for c++ logging?

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
I am trying to use RCLCPP_XX_STREAM function passing directly a message to the stream.  The problem is that I am getting compilation errors because the message ostream operators are not found.

Below I show an example:

```
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <geometry_msgs/msg/pose_stamped.hpp>
[...]
geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped poseMsg = [...];
RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(get_logger(), "posevalue:" << poseMsg);
[...]
```

Error:

> error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream’ and ‘geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped_std::allocator<void >::*pose_type’ {aka ‘geometry_msgs::msg::Pose*std::allocator<void >’})

Where are rclcpp message ostream operators for logging?

Are they available in ROS2? if not, is it planned to support them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364414/where-are-ros2-message-ostream-operators-for-c++-logging?/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2020-10-29

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

UPDATE: It seems the original method below is now deprecated in Humble. You should now use `geometry_msgs::msg::to_yaml()` instead of `rosidl_generator_traits::to_yaml()`

```
warning: ‘std::string rosidl_generator_traits::to_yaml(const Pose&)’ is deprecated: use 
geometry_msgs::msg::to_yaml() instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
```

So, the answer for Humble is

```
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <geometry_msgs/msg/pose_stamped.hpp>
[...]
geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped poseMsg = [...];
RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(get_logger(), "posevalue:" << geometry_msgs::msg::(poseMsg));
[...]
```

---

ORIGINAL:
I had the same issue... here's how to fix it:
use `rosidl_generator_traits::to_yaml(poseMsg)` instead of just `poseMsg`

```
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <geometry_msgs/msg/pose_stamped.hpp>
[...]
geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped poseMsg = [...];
RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(get_logger(), "posevalue:" << rosidl_generator_traits::to_yaml(poseMsg));
[...]
```

I dug through the generated message header files and found it.

---

Originally posted by [m.anderson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2685/m.anderson/) with karma: 91 on 2022-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3